# Rails - 404 when attempting to serve nginx cached image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, nginx, caching, http-status-code-404

I am running a public rails environment that is serving NGINX cached images from the public folder properly when utilizing `<% image_tag('image_location') %>`. A 404 error is arising from an image I am attempting to use as a site-wide background. The image in question is `~/assets/images/Background/roulette.jpg`. I have already ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` hence why every other image on the site is loading its cached copy properly.

The image is currently rendered with: `<div id="sidebar"></div>` with the following css (simplified for readability)...

```
#sidebar {
   background-image: image_url("Background/roulette.jpg");
}
```

Rails is not serving the cached copy of the image, and is trying to serve it from assets. Because I currently have `config.serve_static_assets = false` and `config.assets.compile = false` it is giving me a 404 to the image.

Is there a sane way to use the cached image as my background without changing either config value?

Comment: Can you try changing it to `#sidebar {
   background-image: url("/assets/roulette.jpg");
}`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Same issue as before, 404 error for the image.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using ?

Comment: I'm running an older version, 4.2.10 to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for this is with a dash `-` instead of a underscore `_`. You should format you css like this:

```
#sidebar {
  background-image: image-url("Background/roulette.jpg");
}
```